# MS Access: How to compare and filter data in a column

Tags: ms-access

I am a new user and here is my first question,

I have newly started working on MS access and I am having problems to filter maximum of a column data but according to the data in an another column as well.

Let me explain the situation with a test data:
Table consists of Column A, is a short text, and column B is an integer,

[Test Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB9mK.png)

With a query, i want to filter out only AA-02, BB-04 and CC-06,
I can compare values in a column very easily in excel however i am having problems in Access,

Thanks for your time in advance.

Best Regards,
M.ER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you want the last instance of column B this is a simple sql Totals query.  Using the Query Designer:

[image]

In the SQL Tab (not shown but bottom right of the query designer)

```
SELECT Test.ColumnA, Last(Test.ColumnB) AS ColumnB
FROM Test
GROUP BY Test.ColumnA;
```

**Result:**

### |      ColumnA       |   ColumnB    |

### | AA                 |                  2 |

### | BB                 |                  4 |

| CC                 |                  6 |

Comment: `Last` may not work reliably. Use `Max`.

Comment: or make sure to sort :)